# Gradle DSL method not found: 'debugImplementation()'

Tags: build.gradle, leakcanary

I have included the below dependencies in the gradle.build(app) file to check the memory leaks. But when included the below two dependencies I am getting an error.

```
dependencies {
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
}
```

> Error : Gradle DSL method not found: 'debugImplementation()'

Android Gradle Plugin Version is 3.5.3. And Gradle Version is 5.6.2
Please help in fixing the error.

Comment: Is it still relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Put the dependencies in module gradle file, not project gradle.